# How to visualize data on the map

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I am new to data visualization. I am wondering how to make a map like the on this link: http://statisticalatlas.com/neighborhood/New-York/New-York/Upper-West-Side/Languages

Basically, what I want to do is to represent with deep color for the neighborhoods with high value. For the neighborhoods with low value, the color will not be deep.

I look forward to your reply !

Best, Alimu.

Comment: A [choropleth](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606)?

Comment: yeah,something like that. But i want to do it within NYC neighborhood. How do I define the border and the value of the data ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to know where to get the data from or how to implement this given data?